# Trying to input a fraction and split it into a list but it causes problem when the numbers are more than 1 digit

Tags: python, string, list, input, division

```
fraction = list(input("Enter: "))
print(fraction)
```

When Inputting "99/100" I wanted it to print ["99", "/", "100"] not ['9', '9', '/', '1', '0', '0']

Comment: Remember, the stackoverflow community is not about doing your job, it's about helping you solve problems, specify and think better about your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ".split" for this, for example:

```
thing1 = "abcdef"
thing1.split("c")
```

Gives the output:

```
['ab', 'def']
```

If you're bored and fancy fighting some spaghetti code for your own interest, it can be a fun challenge to code something equivalent to ".split()" yourself. Doing so gets you thinking about how Python works and trying to do it in the smallest big-O can introduce you to some interesting stuff about strings, arrays, and algorithm efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the delimiter, as shown in the question, you can use the `re` module.

```py
import re

fraction = input("Enter: ")
print(re.split("(/)", fraction))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be used `partition` method and not `split` since with `split` will *omit* the separator parameter.

```
"99/100".partition('/')
#('99', '/', '100')
```

For nested fractions other strategies are recommended, `re`,...